# Shoulder deformation when moving bone

Tags: bones

I downloaded this rigged model and works fine until I try to move the elbow above the shoulder. Whenever it goes pass the shoulder, the shoulder moves down.

Here is my blender file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigging is bad, the arm has too much influence on the shoulder while the chest should be the only one to have influence on it with this kind of armature. I've made some corrections and it works "fine". Note that you could create a shoulder (last picture), it would make the rigging better i my opinion:

[image]

Comment: thanks @moonboots ! your suggestions helped